# How to run pylint plugin in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pylint

I have installed `pylint` plugin and restarted the `Intellij IDEA`. It is NOT external tool (so please avoid providing answers on running as an external tool as I know how to).

However I have no `'pylint'` in the tool menu or the code menu.

Is it invoked by running `'Analyze'`? or is there a way to run the `pylint` plugin on `py` files?

Answer (score 9):

This is for the latest IntelliJ IDEA version 2018.3.5 (Community Edition):

- Type "Command ," or click "IntelliJ IDEA -> Preferences..."
- From the list on the left of the popped up window select "Plugins"
- Make sure that on the right top the first tab "Marketplace" is picked if it's not
- Search for "Pylint" and when the item is found, click the green button "Install" associated with the found item

The plugin should then be installed properly.

One can then turn on/off real-time Pylint scan via the same window by navigating in the list on the left: "Editor -> Inspections", then in the list on the right unfolding "Pylint" and finally checking/unchecking the corresponding checkbox on the right of the unfolded item.

One can also in the same window go the very last top-level item within the list on the left named "Other Settings" and unfold it.
Within it there's an item called "Pylint", click on it.
On the top right there should be a button "Test", click on it.
If in a few seconds to the left of the "Test" text there appears a green checkmark, then Pylint is installed correctly.

Finally, to access the actual Pylint window, click "View"->"Tool Windows"->"Pylint"!

Enjoy!

Comment: thanks a lot!! really comprehensive answer!